# Uniquess of Lagrange Multiplier in Calculus of Variations

Tags: sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier

I am currently reading Del Pino & Dolbeault's paper http://capde.cmm.uchile.cl/files/2015/06/pino2002.pdf and I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 4.

We assume that $1<p<\frac{d}{d-2}$ and we want to minimize the functional
$$
G(w)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|\nabla w|^{2}dx+\frac{1}{p+1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|w|^{p+1}dx,
$$
subject to the integral constraint
$$
\frac{1}{2p}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|w|^{2p}dx=J_{\infty},
$$
where $J_{\infty}$ is some constant (which is given but the exact value is not important for the proof).

The minimizer exists and satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$
-\Delta w+w^p=\mu_{\infty}w^{2p-1},
$$
where $\mu_{\infty}$ is the Lagrange multiplier.

So far so good. Now the author claims that the Lagrange multiplier $\mu_{\infty}$ can be uniquely determined by the system
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|\nabla w|^{2}dx+\frac{1}{p+1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|w|^{p+1}dx=I_{\infty}
$$
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|\nabla w|^{2}dx+\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|w|^{p+1}dx=2p\mu_{\infty}J_{\infty}
$$
$$
\frac{d-2}{2d}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|\nabla w|^{2}dx+\frac{1}{p+1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|w|^{p+1}dx=\mu_{\infty}J_{\infty}
$$
where $I_{\infty}=\inf_{w\in\mathcal{X}}G(w)$ ($\mathcal{X}$ denotes the right space so that all the integrals above are well-defined). I understood how to obtain this system.

My first question is: Why is the Lagrange multiplier unique?

Moreover, the author uses the scaling
$$
\overline{w}(x)=\lambda^{\frac{2}{p-1}}w(\lambda x)
$$
to obtain that $\mu_{\infty}=1$. Could someone explain this step to me? I didn't understand this scaling argument.

Comment: The system can be interpreted as a system of linear equations in the unknowns $\int |\nabla w|^2$, $\int |w|^{p+1}$,$\mu_\infty J_\infty$. the resulting system matrix might be invertible?

Comment: I appreciate your comment and your idea. Indeed, using the fact that $1<p<\frac{d}{d-2}$, I could show that the determinant of the resulting matrix is strictly positive and hence invertible.